# External jars in Lotus Notes

Tags: file, jar, external, lotus-notes

I was testing external java code by placing them in the Java agents. Now, am trying to place jar files in our server's file system in the jvm/lib/ext directory. An entry hasnt been made in the notes.ini yet...
The question is, the jar files are existing in 2 places (in the agent and also in servers' file system)... 
Will this result in notesExceptions? 
My agent fails with  Agent  error: java.lang.VerifyError: 
Does any one know what the issue is?

FYI: We will eventually be removing jars from the agent... this is just for testing...

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.VerifyError can occur when you have compiled against a different library than you are using at runtime.

I suspect that the jre version the compiled byte code of the external jars uses is not compatible with domino jre version. Although syntactically correct there are semantic changes that the jvm domino uses cannot accept. If you have access to the source, check the jre version it was compiled for.

Answer (score 0):

Your Domino JRE is older than JRE/JDK version used to compile these JAR files. It is the reason of verification error. Byte code of these JAR files cannot pass JRE verification stage, because this code cannot be *understood* by server JRE.

In most cases there is no necessity to place jar files to server jvm/lib/ext folder.
It is enough to embed these jars to Script Library/Java Agent.

But there are exceptions, for instance for DB2 jdbc driver, that must be located at server jvm/lib/ext folder to let java agents work with DB2 connections.